# Is it possible to detect in which way the player is facing at exactly and store it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have been trying to find out if you can store the direction a player is facing and maybe use it to summon an arrow that shoots in that direction.
I want to make a gun but it would take years and very many command blocks to make a system that will detect every single direction and then shoot the arrow in that direction. That's why I'm asking if there is any way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming 1.13.

To store player's rotation, use `execute store`:

```
execute store result score rot0 store run data get entity @p Rotation[0] 1000000
execute store result score rot1 store run data get entity @p Rotation[1] 1000000
```

which stores his rotation in multidegree